# Why does the mouse pointer move to an unexpected location?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Edit:

I realized owner was running on 1080p, my screen is 1440p.. Do you think it makes any difference? yes, it did. See my comment below.

I have an unmaintained project, that I would like to work on and trying to make sense of the code. However it is clear I am missing something and I didn't notice it. Basically what is needed:

1. to locate offsets of the window and minimap,
2. move cursor to the desired location according to the provided offsets

but it fails to move mouse to desired location. It does move mouse, but ends up somewhere else and I can't find a reason for that. Attached screenshot for demonstration.

Here's the code sample:

X

**window_capture.py**

```
import win32gui
from typing import List
import time

class WindowCapture():

    CLIENT_TOP_BORDER: int = 28.0
    CLIENT_SIDE_BORDER: int = 43.0
    OFFSET_MINIMAP_X: float = 1359.0
    OFFSET_MINIMAP_Y: float = 83.0
    OFFSET_RUN_X: float = 0.0
    OFFSET_RUN_Y: float = 0.0
    OFFSET_LOGOUT_X: float = 0.0
    OFFSET_LOGOUT_Y: float = 0.0

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = self.get_window('Runelite')
        self.center_screen = self.get_center_window(self.window)
        self.center_minimap = self.get_center_minimap(self.window)
        self.run_button = self.get_run_button(self.window)
        self.logout_cross = self.get_logout_cross(self.window)

    def get_window(self, windowname: str) -> List[int]:
        '''Returns the position of the window and the size of the window excluding the borders.'''
        # Get window handle.
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, windowname)
        # Set window to foreground.
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        # Get the window size.
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        # print("debug rect", rect)
        # Adjust size for borders
        # x(left) = 1280
        x = rect[0]
        # y(top) = 28
        y = rect[1] + self.CLIENT_TOP_BORDER
        # w(right) = 2560 - 43 = 2517
        w = rect[2] - self.CLIENT_SIDE_BORDER
        # h(bottom) = 1401 - 28 = 1373
        h = rect[3] - self.CLIENT_TOP_BORDER
        print(x, y, w, h)
        return [x, y, w, h]
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: that might do the trick, I can give it a try, thanks. btw. friend calls it "gorilla debug" haha

Comment: print is the original debugger

Comment: where would you add those print functions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took another day but I managed (at least for now) to understand what's what and get my result.

Original dev did (I guess) window capture on a different resolution, so mouse movement was compatible with his resolution and thus did not work for me. I've updated calc in windows capture and got it working.

Gonna keep learning and thank you for the print debug. It really did help :)